# How to make graphs dealing with a column of frequency in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I have this dataset of breast cancer

---

```
install.packages("vcdExtra")
library(vcdExtra) 
?Cancer
df_cancer<-as.data.frame(Cancer)
```

---

This data set is

```
Survival     Grade    Center Freq
   1     Died Malignant    Boston   35
   2     Surv Malignant    Boston   59
   3     Died    Benign    Boston   47
   4     Surv    Benign    Boston  112
   5     Died Malignant Glamorgan   42
   6     Surv Malignant Glamorgan   77
   7     Died    Benign Glamorgan   26
   8     Surv    Benign Glamorgan   76
```

I want to do graphs to view the supervivence ratio by grade and by center, but I don't know how to deal with the column of frequency because when I do a barplot or anything like that it counts the frequency in the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, you can use `geom_col` with ggplot2

Here is an example with `Cancer` data

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_cancer)+
  geom_col(aes(x = Survival, y = Freq, fill = Grade), position = "dodge")+
  facet_wrap(~Center)
```

[image]

I'd rather be in Boston

Comment: Thank you very much, I was thinking in a plot using lattice like barplot(). But I think it could get easier with this ggplot2 and it is much pretty. 
PS: we'll have to move to Boston